# What is the opposite (antonym) of "live" in TV?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

In TV there is the term **live** that means in "real time". But what is the opposite (antonym) of **live** in TV? Is **non-live**? **pre-recorded**?

E.g.: The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon is **live** - The Tonight Show Starring Jimmy Fallon is **non-live**/**pre-recorded**.

Answer (score 2):

**Pre-recorded** or **taped** are the most common terms in that situation. In most situations, though, you would not need to specify. Most TV is pre-recorded, so unless it's a programme that you would normally expect to be live - like the evening news or a weather report - you don't need to specify.

Comment: And when a TV are repeating (rerunning) a football match and the TV wants to inform (tell) it during the entire broadcast by putting a message on the screen. How is it? **Non-live**?

Comment: @Roi Why are you asking the question again? It's pre-recorded. A TV channel shows on the screen: pre-recorded and the date, usually.

Answer (score 1):

It can be a **rebroadcast** or a **repeat**.

[Rebroadcast](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rebroadcast):

> noun (Broadcasting) a television or radio programme that is shown or put on again

From Collins. The word rebroadcast tends to imply that the original broadcast was live. The editing might reflect that. The word "rebroadcast" can also be used as a verb, e.g.

> The final is on live now, but it’ll be **rebroadcast** tomorrow afternoon.

You might also see it at the start of a (pre-recorded) topical show, or one that contains time dependent data. For example, some of the property shows which have details of house prices might be preceded with "This show was originally broadcast in September 2014".

And a "repeat" is simply the same show repeated, regardless of whether it was originally live or pre-recorded.